# Soong UI permission denied AOSP build

Tags: android, linux, bash, android-source

I am running android 9 AOSP. But after using source `build/envsetup.sh`
it successfully runs. But when I use,

```
administrator@administrator:ao9/android_build$ lunch sabresd_6dq-userdebug
```

I get:

`bash: build/soong/soong_ui.bash: Permission denied`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found Solution.

administrator@administrator:ao9$ **chmod -R 777 android_build**

---

The reason for running this command is that the files do not have read, write and execute permissions for every user. This could have happened because you copied it from another filesystem with permissions already set, it likely does not happen is you download it straight to the box you are using.

Read [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/) for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it as `sudo`:

```
sudo lunch sabresd_6dq-userdebug
```

Comment: I tired that too. No use.

Comment: Please check this link. There's a similar issue. Maybe it will help. https://community.nxp.com/thread/386224

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202205/discussion-between-akshay-anurag-and-shadow).

Comment: But that's for shell. I am getting error at bash. I tried changing by giving to root too. (sudo su)